# Acados package. Matlab and CMake

Tags: matlab, cmake, mingw

I am currently working with matlab and I have been trying to install one of the app_ons of matlab called mingw. However, there are some steps before installing such as the clonation of the acados directory and build acados. Nevertheless, in the last step (build acados),

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D BLASFEO_TARGET=GENERIC -D HPIPM_TARGET=GENERIC -D ACADOS_INSTALL_DIR=.. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DACADOS_EXAMPLES=OFF -DACADOS_UNIT_TESTS=OFF ..
mingw32-make.exe -j4
mingw32-make.exe install
```

the execution of that code in the console shows the next error

```
CMake Error at external/CMakelists.txt:32 (add_subdirectory):

C:/Users/LP/acados/external/balsfeo

does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file
```

I have checked and that folder actually is empty but I do not know how to fix that problem because I have followed the other steps correctly and they do not show additional steps or advices. Could you please help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `mkdir -p build` is unix style call, on windows `mkdir` does not have options. This call would create a directory called `-p`, not `build`. Try `mkdir build`.

Comment: As you can see online - https://github.com/acados/acados/tree/master/external - subdirectories in the `external/` directory are **git submodules**. This is why [README](https://github.com/acados/acados/blob/master/README.md#installation) for acados specifies the first installation step as `git submodule update --recursive --init`, which clones these submodules. You missed that step.